# tabular or tabularx: how to align the first column to the top?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

In the example below, I would like the star to be aligned to the very top (as much as possible). Is it possible and if yes how to do it?

I'm looking for a generic solution as I could replace the integral by other contents, with possibly a higher height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0mm}c}
$\star$ &
${\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt = 1}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about `\raisebox{8pt}{$\star$}`?  Is that too manual?

Comment: Way Beyond the Stars too much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APPROACH #1

The `\upstar` macro creates a row with just a star in column one, and then does an artificial shift to place it properly relative to the top of row 2.  But in your input, it looks like part of row 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\upstar{$\star$ \\[\dimexpr5pt-\normalbaselineskip]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0mm}c}
\upstar& ${\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt = 1}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

APPROACH #2

Here, I give a `\shiftdown` macro that might suffice for columns that are not the first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\shiftdown[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr2pt-\ht0}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0mm}c}
$\star$ &
\shiftdown{${\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt = 1}$}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the similar solution but with a `shiftup` for the star?

Comment: @Colas  For that, I would just use Approach 1 of my edited answer.

Comment: How could I "grab" the height `heightContent` of the content of the second column and before that and do something like `\raisebox{heightContent}{$\star$}`?

Comment: @Colas I don't know of such a way, short of a massive rewrite of `tabular`.  Of course, that doesn't mean it is impossible, I just don't know enough to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\def\RB#1{\raisebox{\dimexpr(-\height-\depth)/2}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$\star$  & \RB{$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt = 1$}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to move the star then use `\vphantom` for the height of the
integral. Then you do not need fixed values for the shift:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\RBo#1{\raisebox{\dimexpr+\height+\depth}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\RBo{$\star\vphantom{\int}$}  & $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt = 1$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And, of course, with package `amsmath` you can simply use:

```
$\displaystyle\sideset{^\star}{_0^1}\int f(t) dt = 1$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that either with a hack (a real integral in the first column printed in white, with a black star as  upper bound) or with the `prescript` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor, tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0mm}c}
$\color{white}\displaystyle\int^{\color{black}\star}$ &
$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt = 1 $ \\[4ex]
 & $\displaystyle \prescript{\star\mkern-6mu}{}{\int_0^1} f(t) dt = 1$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]